# backbone.js: set focus to input after render

Tags: jquery, focus, backbone.js, setfocus

I have a Model that has 1 input. Also, I have a Collection. Now, when I add a model to the collection, I want to set the focus to it's input.
To be precise, I need to set the focus on the newly created model view's input.

However, I can't seem to get it to work. Here's my function that adds the model's view to the collection view:

```
addOne: function(InvoiceItem) {
    var view = new InvoiceItemView({model: InvoiceItem});
    this.$('tr[data-id="'+InvoiceItem.get('after')+'"]').after(view.render().el);
    this.$('tr[data-id="'+InvoiceItem.cid+'"]').css('background', 'green');
    this.$('tr[data-id="'+InvoiceItem.cid+'"] input').focus();
},
```

The problem is, the third call: `this.$('tr[data-id="'+InvoiceItem.cid+'"] input').focus();` does not do anything. And it's weird, because it seems that I can only do DOM manipulation on the root element `tr`, and on nothing else besides that.

It seems to me that jQuery doesn't know that the element exists, which is weird, because when I do `alert(this.$('tr[data-id="'+InvoiceItem.cid+'"] input').length)` I get 1, which indicates that the element exists.

What it is that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using _.defer fixed my problem:

```
var $this = this;
_.defer(function(){
  $this.$('tr[data-id="'+InvoiceItem.cid+'"] input').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `this.$('tr[data-id="'+InvoiceItem.cid+'"] input').focus();`

try this

```
$(view.render().el).find('input').focus();
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work and I think I know why: the collection view gets re-rendered because the collection changes once I add the item to the view. And re-rendering loses focus from any input... Is there a way to restore the focus after re-render?

Comment: My first guess was that it's because the collection view gets re-rendered, but that doesn't seem to be the case (I tried with simple alert() to see if the render gets triggered).
It's weird because even if i do just $('input').hide() - it doesn't do anything. EDIT: actually it seems that occasionally, after a certai amount of time has passed, it seems to hide the first row's input

Comment: @ragulka Can you share your collection, model and view code. There's probably some events firing that's causing it

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem very similar to yours and ended up here while searching for a solution.  Your post was a few months ago so you probably have moved past this, but hopefully this will help someone else.  I was able to solve the problem using [jQuery's `ready` function handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).  I always thought it could only be used on the `document` but you can use it on subnodes as well.  Try this:

```
addOne: function(InvoiceItem) {
  var view = new InvoiceItemView({model: InvoiceItem});
  $('tr[data-id="'+InvoiceItem.get('after')+'"]').ready(function(){
    $('tr[data-id="'+InvoiceItem.cid+'"]').css('background', 'green');
    $('tr[data-id="'+InvoiceItem.cid+'"] input').focus();
  });
  $('tr[data-id="'+InvoiceItem.get('after')+'"]').after(view.render().el);
```

Comment: Although it can be used on subnodes, it won't wait for subnodes to become ready, but just *wait for the DOM become **safe** to manipulate*. This has exactly the same effect of $`(function(){console.log('ready')})`